# Summary list on Blog page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: blog

Is there an easy way to edit the Summary list???

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with editing this? There is almost always a way in SharePoint.

Comment: On all web parts there is a summary list and I was wondering if there is a way to get to the actual summary list to edit it (add/remove columns, etc) instead of creating a custom list. Basically this is something I would like to do the blog page.

Comment: Please edit your question to expand with this additional information. As it stands it isn't really answerable. See our [FAQ]

(http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.